# Hardware accelerated mjpeg encoding with ffmpeg

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I have this batch file that I need to convert videos into MJPEG but using Hardware acceleration on a machine with AMD GPU (Vega 8 and RX560X specifically)

```
echo off
set arg1=%1
shift
ffmpeg -i %arg1% -vcodec mjpeg_vaapi -vf scale=min'(960,iw)':-1 -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 22050 -ac 2 -r 20 -q:v 5s -f avi %arg1%.mojo
```

And I'm using `ffmpeg version 4.4-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers`

Running the batch throws `Unknown encoder 'mjpeg_vaapi'`

Which ffmpeg version contains the MJPEG encoder that can encode with hardware acceleration?

Comment: Have you read [Hardware/VAAPI – FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/VAAPI)? It explains the correct way to use vaapi

Comment: Apparently no (m)jpeg support yet: http://ffmpeg.org/general.html#AMD-AMF_002fVCE (For the record vaapi is Linux or so only)

Comment: According to the FFMPEG hardware acceleration overview VAAPI accel is not available on Windows (only on Linux): https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro

Comment: Another MJPEG hardware accelerated encoder is mjpeg_qsv ([Quick Sync](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/QuickSync) / libmfx), bit it's for Intel.